# SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select" in Dbeaver PostgreSQL editor

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

```
insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id)
select imjp_number, imct_id
from dummy_data_03032021
on conflict (jp_number) do update 
  set ct_id = select imct_id from dummy_data_03032021 where imjp_number=jp_number;
```

SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"
Position: 166

I am updating ct_id value into table dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 from dummy_data_03032021 if jpnumber=imjp_number otherwise I have to insert both jp_number and ct_id value into table dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 from dummy_data_03032021 keeping other column value intact

Either I tried this also

```
UPDATE dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 SET dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021.jp_number=dummy_data_03032021.imjp_number, dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021.ct_id= dummy_data_03032021.imct_id WHERE dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021.jp_number=dummy_data_03032021.imjp_number;
INSERT INTO dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id) SELECT imjp_number,imct_id from dummy_data_03032021 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dummy_data_03032021 WHERE dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021.jp_number=dummy_data_03032021.imjp_number);
```

Got error:SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "dummy_data_03032021"
Position: 222

USING EXCLUDED  got beloew error
SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

```
insert into dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021 (jp_number, ct_id)
select imjp_number, imct_id
from dummy_data_03032021
on conflict (jp_number) do update set ct_id = EXCLUDED.ct_id
```

Comment: @S-Man please refer https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=62c061f9e8becbe0e7e54263218cbff5

Comment: Why don't you use the standard EXLCUDED-syntax? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens I used Excluded but getting error "SQL Error [42P10]: ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification"

Comment: `create unique index on dwb_weekly_snapshot_03032021  (jp_number)`